# Unable to sort files by modified date/time in Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-storage-explorer

We have logs on our application server hosted in Azure cloud. We want to show the logs to the customer who does not have access to the application server directly. We decided to use Azure sync to synchronize the logs from the app server to Azure File storage and enable view those logs from Azure Storage Explorer. The sync all works fine, but I am unable to sort the logs based on modified date-time. Our production server has 1000s of log files and it is not easy to search through the files to check logs. Any idea how to bring the modified date-time in Storage explorer? Or Is there any another approach?

Comment: Where are these logs store? In Blob Storage? I can sort blobs by "Last Modified" column just fine. Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri-AIS. We use Azure File Storage to store the logs. Does Azure File Sync work well with Blobs?

Comment: Aah, I see. So basically you're using Azure File Share to store these logs. Correct?

Comment: yes, we use Azure File Share to store the logs.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure file explorer App, fileshares don't have the date column, only Blob containers do, indeed.
However, if you mount the fileshare as a drive on your computer, you'll get the date info and will be able to sort.
The command script (Powershell) to mount the fileshare as a drive on Windows is available in the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Azure Storage Explorer View Options]

[image]

1. Click the `View Options` button.
2. Click the `Flat` radio button, under `List Mode`.
3. Click the `Last Modified` header to sort by date.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to sort ALL your files, regardless the batch size.

In Settings, you need to enable the Global Sort:

[image: Edit --> Settings]

[image: Data Explorers section]